# Fixing an error in Java (by only changing one line)

Tags: java

My objective is to fix an issue where every shoppingcart is assigned the same number (1). The big issues here is that I only get to edit existing lines. I know that the reason each shoppingcart gets the same number is because each shoppingcart gets their own arraylist when you run the code. My problem is that I can't figure out how to fix it without adding lines or another class.

```
public class Shoppingcart {

    private ArrayList<Shoppingcart> allCarts = new ArrayList<Shoppingcart>();

    public int number;

    public Shoppingcart(){
        allCarts.add(this);
        this.number = allCarts.size();
    }
```

Comment: search for the meaning of **static** keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what if you add the static keyword for that arrayList?

Comment: Oh my god, thank you. I knew I missed something extremely simple.